# HBASE CellUtil vs KeyValue

Tags: hbase, cell

I have a simple question. Should I use CellUtil Class like this:

```
 for (Cell cell : result.rawCells()) {
            byte[] family = CellUtil.cloneFamily(cell);
            byte[] column = CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell);
            byte[] value = CellUtil.cloneValue(cell);
            System.out.println("\t" + Bytes.toString(family) + ":" + Bytes.toString(column) + " = " + Bytes.toString(value));
        }
```

or KeyValue Class for accessing result cell

```
for(KeyValue kv : result.list()){
            String family = new String(kv.getFamily());
            System.out.println(family);
            String qualifier = new String(kv.getQualifier());
            System.out.println(qualifier);
            System.out.println(new String(kv.getValue()));

        }
```

Do KeyValue is deprecated?

Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

KeyValue is not deprecated but its methods like getFamily,getQualifier,getValue etc. are. 
In API documentation you can see that CellUtil class methods are recommended(for client side) and Cell interface methods for server-side.
This is because according to HBase docs,
KeyValue is the fundamental HBase type and it is recommended that HBase applications and users should use the Cell interface and avoid directly using KeyValue and member functions not defined in Cell.

Answer (score 0):

see this link: https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/KeyValue.html

> If being used client-side, the primary methods to access individual fields are getRowArray(), getFamilyArray(), getQualifierArray(), getTimestamp(), and getValueArray(). These methods allocate new byte arrays and return copies. Avoid their use server-side.